# Can Wolfram Development Platform communicate in real time?

Tags: wolfram-cloud, real-time, socket, networking

Is it possible for Wolfam Development Platform to use sockets or anything other for real time communication? For example, in Javascript I can use RethinkDb, Firebase, socket.io or something similar. For Java I can use sockets. For .NET SignalR. Is it a way to enable real time communication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is now an experimental feature to communicate in real-time in Wolfram:

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Channel-BasedCommunication.html

It can be used to communicate between two Wolfram Clouds. You can also simulate ChannelSend function by sending HTTP query.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to sockets with [SocketConnect](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SocketConnect.html), but I'm not aware of a built-in way to bind a socket.

Comment: Does that work in the cloud? (I have no experience with it.)

Comment: Seems like the any option that is somewhat close to what we are trying to achieve.